# Unable to delete the Persistent Volumes (PVs) associated with the helm release of a micro service deployment in JenkinsX

Tags: okd, jenkins-x

**Summary:**

I have deployed a microservice in OKD cluster through JenkinsX and am trying to delete the Persistent Volumes (PVs) associated with a helm release right after the deployment. So I found the following command from the jx documentation,

```
jx step helm delete <release_name> -n <namespace>
```

**Steps to reproduce the behavior:**

Deploy a service using jx preview command with release name,

```
jx preview --app $APP_NAME --dir ../.. --release preview-$APP_NAME
```

**Expected behavior:**

The jx step helm delete should remove the Persistent volumes (PVs) associated with the micro service deployment.

**Actual behavior:**

The above delete command is unable to delete the PVs which makes the promotion to staging build fails with port error.

**Jx version:**

The output of jx version is:

```
NAME               VERSION
jx                 2.0.785
jenkins x platform 2.0.1973
Kubernetes cluster v1.11.0+d4cacc0
kubectl            v1.11.0+d4cacc0
helm client        Client: v2.12.0+gd325d2a
git                2.22.0
Operating System   "CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)"
```

**Jenkins type:**

[ ] Serverless Jenkins X Pipelines (Tekton + Prow)

[*] Classic Jenkins

**Kubernetes cluster:**

Openstack cluster with 1 master and 2 worker nodes.

I need to delete the PVs through jx's jenkinsfile so tried using,

```
1. jx step helm delete <release_name> -n <namespace> ["Unable to delete PVs"]
2. helm delete purge <release_name> ["unable to list/delete the release created through jx helm"]
3. oc/kubectl commands are not working through Jenkinsfile.
```

But nothing helps. So, please suggest me anyway that I can delete PVs through Jenkinsfile of jx.

Answer (score 0):

`jx step helm delete` doesn't remove a PV. `helm delete` also doesn't remove a PV and it's an expected behaviour. 
You need to use `--purge` option to completely delete Helm release with all PV associate with it. e.g. `jx step helm delete <release_name> -n <namespace> --purge`